# KendoUI multiple axis Chart (mixed chart with Bubble and Column chart types)

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mobile, kendo-treeview, kendo-chart

I am using Telerik for Silverlight (for desktop browsers) and Kendo UI (for mobile browsers) in my data visualisation project.

Multi axis chart of types Bubble and Column works fine in Silverlight. But the same does not work in Kendo UI. Kendo just draws Column and not the bubbles. Anybody knows the way to achieve this in Kendo UI?

Please see my two images below:

1. Desktop Silverlight Chart

[image: Chart drawn using Telerik for Silverlight]

2. Mobile (Kendo UI) Chart

[image: Chart Drawn using Kendo UI]

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by creating multiple (in your case two) series. One for column and one for bubble.

Example can be found here: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/bar-charts/multiple-axes

If you've tried this and it doesn't work, post some code so we can debug. :)